# Alamofire Priority Queue

Tags: ios, swift, queue, alamofire

I am using Alamofire as my networking library for my Swift app. Is there a way to keep a "priority queue" of network requests with Alamofire? I believe I saw this feature in a library in the past but I can no longer find it or find other posts about this.

Let's say I open a page in my application and it starts to make a few requests. First it gets some JSON, which is fast and no problem.

From that JSON, it pulls out some information and then starts downloading images. These images have the potential to be quite large and take many seconds (~30 seconds or more sometimes). But the tricky part is that the user has the option to move on to the next page before the image(s) finish downloading.

If the user moves on to the next page before the image downloading is done, is it possible to move it on to a lower priority queue? So that when the images on the next page start loading they will go faster? I would even be open to pausing the old one entirely until the new requests are finished if that is even possible.

Keep in mind I am open to many suggestions. I have a lot of freedom with my implementation. So if this is a different library, or different mechanism in iOS that is fine. Even if I continue to use Alamofire for JSON and do all my image downloading and management with something else that would be alright too.

Also, probably irrelevant but I will add it here. I'm using https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage for caching my images once they're fully downloaded. Which is why I don't want to cancel the request completely. I need it to finish and then it won't happen again.

TL;DR I want a fast queue and a slow queue with the ability to move things from the fast queue to the slow queue before they are finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered managing a NSOperationQueue? This [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift) might be helpful. In his example, he pauses the downloads as they scroll off the page, but I believe you could adjust the queuePriority property of the NSOperation objects instead.